# Деплой на мастер сервер

Tags: php, git

На данный момент в проекте есть дев сервер и у каждого разработчика своё локальное окружение приближенное к реальному.

Как происходит деплой на мастер сервер не заходится же на  сервак и не делается `git pull` ?

Comment: jenkins например. Сам зайдет и сделает ))

Answer (score 5):

Вы спросили в основном про доставку файлов на сервер (`git pull` может сделать только это). В случае простого веб-приложения этого бывает достаточно, при условии что у вас [сервер-снежинка](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SnowflakeServer.html) и вы всё равно его когда-то конфигурируете руками.

Как только приложение становится немного сложнее, простой доставки файлов становится недостаточно. В этом случае становится выгодно автоматизировать развертывание, использовать специализированные инструменты и [серверы-фениксы](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PhoenixServer.html).

Я пытался кратко написать о разных способах и о их преимуществах и недостатках, но понял, что их слишком много и все характеристики очень сильно зависят от задачи.

Поэтому вот вам что-то вроде небольшой ментальной карты (mindmap). Возможно, о каких-то вопросах вы ещё не думали и не рассматривали какие-то из вариантов. Надеюсь, она поможет вам сделать выбор или хотя бы полнее увидеть задачу.

Итак, три основных вопроса:

1. **Что делать?** Из чего вообще состоит развёртывание:

   - Доставить обновлённое приложение на сервер. Способы:

     - `git pull` на сервере. Плохо масштабируется.
     - Закинуть файлы с помощью `rsync`. Хорошо масштабируется.
     - Закинуть файлы по FTP, прибежать с флешкой к серверу, отправить Почтой России. В общем, разные способы для любителей преодолевать трудности.
     - Упаковать в пакет некоторого пакетного менеджера, закинуть в репозиторий. Для веб-приложения может быть слишком сложно и медленно. Но хорошо, если вы продаёте приложение и должны его как-то распространять.
     - Упаковать в образ, развернуть в контейнере. Аналогично прошлому пункту.
   - Сконфигурировать приложение.
   - Установить и сконфигурировать сторонние приложения (зависимости).
   - Запустить и перезапустить процессы.
   - Поднять базу данных.
   - Получить какие-нибудь нужные для работы данные.
   - (Тут может быть очень много разных задач.)
   - ...
2. **Как делать?** Каким инструментом развертывать приложение:

   - Руками по памяти.
   - Написать скрипт и запускать его.
   - Написать сценарий для системы управления конфигурациями.
   - Распространять готовый образ
   - (тоже много способов)
3. **Когда делать?** Как инициировать развертывание новой версии:

   - Вручную. Ответственный за релиз человек запускает инструмент из прошлого пункта или жмет кнопку на сервере интеграции, который использует этот инструмент.
   - Автоматически по реакции на изменения в системе контроля версий. Ответственный за релиз человек делает коммит в `master` или создаёт и пушит на сервер новый тег. Сервер реагирует и использует инструмент развертывания.

Answer (score 2):

И так можно, но конечно лучше использовать какой-нибудь Continuous Integration, например, [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/) или [go](https://www.thoughtworks.com/go/). В самом простом варианте можно настроить как [Continuous deployment](https://docs.gocd.io/current/navigation/pipelines_dashboard_page.html).

Принцип работы приблизительно такой.

В CI настраивается git, время опроса, сервера. И раз в несколько минут опрашивается репозиторий на изменения по какой-нибудь ветке. И выливаются изменения на тестовый.

Comment: А Teamcity это из той оперы ?

Comment: Да, Teamcity это CI. С ним дело не имел, но в нете есть примеры с его использованием. На хабре статейка есть http://makedev.org/articles/ci.html