# Синхронизация проекта на сервере Linux с github

Tags: linux, node.js, git, развертывание

Всем привет! Подскажите может уже есть готовое решение моей проблемы. Ситуация такая, есть у меня локально проект NodeJS допустим я сделал изменения и закомитил на гитхаб, хотелось бы что бы мой амазоновский сервер на Linux автоматически перекачал изменённые файлы и перезапустил проект. Такую систему я видел на OpenShift.

Comment: Есть вебхуки и Travis CI

Comment: Минут 10 уже думаю, как бы так ответить, чтобы не на пять страниц.

Answer (score 6):

Когда вы делаете `git push` и на гитхабе появляется новый коммит, где-то должен выполниться код, который сделает всю работу.

## Исполнители

Есть следующие варианты «исполнителей»:

- Использовать **сервер [непрерывной интеграции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470453/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/471182?s=18%7C0.1096#471182)**. Это приложение, которое реагирует на коммиты и выполняет какие-либо задачи с содержимым каждого коммита. Обычно эти задачи описываются в определенном файле проекта, который версионируется как любой другой код.

  Для того, чтобы его «уведомить» о появлении нового коммита, нужно будет использовать [веб-хуки](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) — HTTP POST запросы с заданным содержимым, которые отправляет GitHub. Документация к конкретному серверу расскажет вам, как интегрировать его с GitHub.

  Сервер CI – это современный, хорошо поддерживаемый и масштабируемый путь. Рекомендую.

  Примеры:

  - облачные: Travis CI, Circle CI. Я также люблю GitLab CI, но он работает только с GitLab (т.е. не GitHub). Во всех трех есть бесплатные подписки для opensource-проектов.
  - self-hosted: Jenkins, TeamCity, Bamboo.
- **Сервер с приложением** может сам выкачивать изменения, собирать и разворачивать проект, получая уведомление через веб-хук. Для этого понадобится держать на нём:

  - Всё сборочное окружение,
  - git и репозиторий с проектом,
  - Открытый порт для получения команд.

  Этот способ плох по множеству причин: уязвимость, лишнее окружение, замусоренный сервер, плохо масштабируется, труднее восстанавливать «с чистого листа». Знайте, что так можно, но, пожалуйста, не делайте так.
- **git hooks**. Скрипты, которые запускает git на сервере при определенных условиях, например при получении коммитов. Хуки можно установить на свой сервер, например, если у вас self-hosted GitHub. На github.com, насколько я знаю, их установить нельзя.

  Вырожденный случай, наследующий всё плохое от последних двух вариантов, — когда один сервер используется как git-сервер для командной работы, с помощью гит-хуков сам на себе собирает код и публикует его сам себе куда-нибудь в `/srv/www/project`. Это отличный способ потерять всё и сразу.

## Задачи

А работа состоит из следующих основных этапов:

1. **Сборка проекта** из исходного кода. Так же, как вы обычно собираете сайт на своей машине.

   **Артефакты сборки** — это различные «полезные» файлы, которые являются результатом сборки. Например, папка с файлами сайта — это артефакт, а папка `node_modules` — не артефакт.
2. **Развертывание проекта** в каком-либо окружении. Доставка артефактов и, если необходимо, операции администрирования.

   Развертывание в боевом окружении должно производиться из одной установленной стабильной ветки с осмысленным названием: `master`, `production` и т.п. Из других веток код разворачивается в тестовые окружения либо никуда.

   - Тут подробнее про конкретные задачи и различные способы их выполнения: [Деплой на мастер сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637352/181472).
   - Вот очень устаревший ответ, описывающий доставку артефактов с помощью rsync и c помощью git (тот самый вырожденный случай). Из ценного там — про rsync. [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472).